# QDataWidgetMapper with QComboBox controls, dynamically changing the available items in the drop down

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm writing an editor that is used to configure some properties for a different system.  I have a table model working for displaying and editing all the data, it's setup like:

```
           RowCount | Text1Position | Text1 | Text2Position | Text2 | text3Position | ....
         +----------+---------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------------+-----+
Graphic1 |    8     |       1       | 'xyz' |       3       | 'abc' |       2       |    
         +----------+---------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------------+-----+
Graphic2 |    16    |       16      | 'xyz' |      15       | 'abc' |       14      |    
         +----------+---------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------------+-----+
```

There are 32 pairs of texts and positions and a column to for row count. (This is for an HMI popup populated from values stored in a PLC AOI, it has 32 possible rows that can be rearranged in any order)  The row count column is used to determine the popup graphic, there's sizes like 8/16/32.

For my GUI, I used QDataWidgetMapper to map each control on my editor panel to a column in the model.  Then I have a listview that changes the current index of the mapper.  Each position column is mapped to a QComboBox.  I would like to set it up to where the dropdown of each combobox only shows the positions left.  Position 0 is 'Hidden', so that should be always be an option. So for the row Graphic1 above, the only items in the drop down should be: ['Hidden', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].

I think I want to use a proxy model that only shows the available positions, but I haven't been able to find an example.  Right now I'm using one QStringListModel as the source model for the all comboboxes.  I have also tried overriding the showPopup method to populate each combobox's items with the available ones, but that breaks the column mapping and then it no longer updates.

In the sample code below, I want the combobox dropdowns to only show values between 0 and the whatever is selected in `cboRows` minus any numbers selected in the other comboboxes.  Any advice on how to implement that?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QDataWidgetMapper, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel
import sys


class View(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.lblRowNumber = QLabel()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lblRowNumber, 0, 0)

        self.cboRows = QComboBox()
        self.cboRows.addItems([str(x) for x in [8, 16, 24, 32]])
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cboRows, 1, 0)

        for i in range(32):
            pos_name = f'cboPosition{i}'
            txt_name = f'txtText{i}'
            setattr(self, pos_name, QComboBox())
            setattr(self, txt_name, QLineEdit())

            self.layout.addWidget(getattr(self, pos_name), i+2, 0)
            self.layout.addWidget(getattr(self, txt_name), i+2, 1)

            getattr(self, pos_name).addItems([f'{i}' for i in range(32)])

        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()

    def map_model(self, model):
        self.mapper.setModel(model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.cboRows, 0)

        col = 1
        for i in range(32):
            self.mapper.addMapping(getattr(self, f'cboPosition{i}'), col)
            col += 1
            self.mapper.addMapping(getattr(self, f'txtText{i}'), col)
            col += 1

    def next_row(self):
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex((self.mapper.currentIndex() + 1) % self.mapper.model().rowCount())
        self.lblRowNumber.setText(f'Row: {self.mapper.currentIndex()}')


class Model(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, plc=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.plc = plc
        self.rows = {}

        self._build()

    def _build(self):
        tags = {'Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3', 'Tag4', 'Tag5'}

        for row_idx, tag in enumerate(tags):
            row = [16]

            for i in range(32):
                row.append(0)
                row.append('Description')

            self.rows[row_idx] = row

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.rows)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.rows[0]) if self.rows else 0

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        val = self.rows[index.row()][index.column()]
        return val

    def setData(self, index, value, role=None):
        self.rows[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])

    m = Model()
    v = View()
    v.map_model(m)
    v.mapper.setCurrentIndex(0)

    w = QWidget()
    l = QVBoxLayout(w)
    btn = QPushButton('Next Row')
    btn.clicked.connect(v.next_row)
    l.addWidget(btn)
    l.addWidget(v)

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If you want us to help you and also understand you better you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: I added an example that is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do

Comment: You want that the comboboxes that are below cboRows can only be between 0 and the number selected by cboRows minus the ones chosen by the other comboboxes that are different from 0 since this is chosen by default. I am right?

Comment: Correct, sorry I didn't word that in the best way.